# Python Relative import not working

Tags: python, import

```
main_package
 |
 | __init__.py
 | folder_1
 |  | __init__.py
 |  |script_a.py
 |  |
 | folder_2
 |  | __init__.py
 |  | script_b.py
```

I want to access script_b from script_a and import b_class with relative import

script_a.py:

```
from ..folder2.script_b import b_class
```

Gives me error => ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

http://dosya.co/y6aqrgp993fu/main_package.rar.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try, as it is package

```
from main_package.folder_2.script_b import b_class
```

OR

```
from .main_package.folder_2.script_b import b_class
```

OR (May be patch)

```
import sys
sys.path.append(pathofyourproject) // `/home/prject`
import folder_2.script_b.py
```

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder_2'

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main_package'

Comment: add __init__.py into main_package folder

Comment: I uploaded directory you can download it

Comment: the last one:                                                                                            
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\main_package")
import folder_2.script_b.py      gives me  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder_2.script_b.py'; 'folder_2.script_b' is not a package

Comment: I made a mistake in the last one.Last one is working.folder_2.script_b.py must be folder_2.script_b